# How to make a view with picker and toolbar stay at the bottom of iphone screen

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder

I am using this code and its placing my view at the top of the viewing area instead of the bottom. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am not creating the view in swift because I already have it created in IB with a toolbar and pickerview inside it.

```
let height = view.frame.size.height

yearView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)
```

Even if I use the y coordinate and say 50 the view wont budge from the top. All I am trying to do is place this subview at the bottom of any sized phone's screen so they can select a value inside the view.

Comment: @Nick89 I saw you answer this but i used your code and no luck, any ideas?

Comment: auto layout enabled ??

Comment: print out the rect value you set to yearView's frame

Comment: Yes auto layout enabled, I think i do have constraints on it so it will stay at the bottom, should i remove those?

Comment: Here is the output of the rect, (0.0, 486.0, 414.0, 250.0)

Comment: On a 6 plus just so you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yearView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)
```

Try moving it out of the ViewDidLoad, you need to position that view whenever you unhide it, otherwise it will not show.

Comment: What do you mean place above a view? I tried placing it above self.view but its still at the top.

Comment: So I placed it above a switch i have thats in the screen on the phone but its still at the top. And I removed constraints but its still at the very top. Let me know if Im doing something wrong.

Comment: let height = view.frame.size.height
        
            yearView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 250, width:     self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

            self.view.insertSubview(yearView, aboveSubview: bothSwitch)

Comment: @Suzukijak3 Okay so this view (yearView), do you want it to be at the back? Behind the bothSwitch? If you do, then use the `insertSubview(yearView, belowSubview: bothSwitch)` instead. Or you could try `sendSubviewToBack(yearView)` . Let me know if issues

Comment: Ok I'll try that, the whole issue is its just not positioned at the bottom of the viewing screen. Will that fix it? I know with alertViews you can specify 0,0 and it will be dead center of the viewing screen. I just want that but at the bottom.

Comment: Ok I tried both those, the good news is the toolbar showed up but even when i bring it to the front the textfield that popped it is in front of it. And its still at the top of the screen vs bottom.

Comment: @Suzukijak3 Ah okay, sorry I thought you mean't in terms of layering the views. Okay, I have created this myself and it works fine, Could you please edit your original question, and show all of your code, so I can see where we are going wrong.

Comment: Edited, but not much. Thats all the code I am using to position it. @Nick89

Comment: @Suzukijak3 hmm, okay well the error must lie elsewhere in the project? Is there a lot to the project, if you wanted to send me the folder containing all the files I don't mind having a quick look through to see if i cant spot any errors? But without seeing the rest of it, it's hard to say what's causing this.

Comment: I figured it out, i was positioning it in the wrong place. Just edit your answer and tell me that I need to position that view whenever I unhide it. It wasn't positioning it in viewdidload

Comment: If you edit it, I will accept your answer. Thanks for the help @Nick89

Comment: Can you use this code and get rid of the other code in your answer as it doesn't pertain to the question really?         yearView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250) @Nick89